# `@each` loop in Sass to declare dynamic id?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following Sass code:

```
@each $message_color in red, blue, black {
    .#{$message_color}-font-color{
        color: $message_color;
    }
}
```

and the result is

```
/* line 2, ../sass/styles.scss */ 
.red-font-color { color: red; }

/* line 2, ../sass/styles.scss */ 
.blue-font-color { color: blue; }

/* line 2, ../sass/styles.scss */ 
.black-font-color { color: black; }
```

My question now, how can I create this result

```
/* line 2, ../sass/styles.scss */
#red-font-color { color: red; }

/* line 2, ../sass/styles.scss */
#blue-font-color { color: blue; }

/* line 2, ../sass/styles.scss */
#black-font-color { color: black; }
```

I need generate an `# selector` not `class selector`...

Comment: +1 I'm really interested in this question too, been wondering about it for a week or so.

Comment: Note that [using IDs is a bad practice](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/), even more when it doesn’t concern main elements such as layout.

Comment: MR LeBen, thank you very much for nice info, your talk was Truth and helpful ... 

about me I like use classes selector more than id, since its reusable and we can work with script more best...

thanks for your knowledge ... and I will subscribe you ^_^ ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in netbeans ##{$message_color} error but is correct in sass an scss